# Custom option file or image save with extension in magento2

Tags: extensions, custom, option

I want to save custom option file save with extension.

Actually i make pdf and print image in this way

```
$optionvalue["fullpath"]=/var/www/html/magento2/pub/media/custom_options/quote/1/_/usO23kzyNEu62DMTwcOsB7XX6HHX0RVI
$image=\Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($optionvalue["fullpath"]);
        $page->drawImage($image, 300,300, 50,50);
```

It give error `Unknown extension` when i give use this `$image=\Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($optionvalue["fullpath"]);`

[image]

When use this `$image=\Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($optionvalue["fullpath"].'png');` 
then it not found file

[image]

Now has any way to save custom option file save with **extension**

Comment: Share a screenshot of the error and mention your Magento version.

Comment: @MohitRane i update my question please check it

Answer (score 0):

This extension is very helpful and saves your time. https://marketplace.magento.com/encoresky-customoptionimage.html